# Question about Differential Equations, why is there no constant for $x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> The following equation is in the form$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(y)$$ 
>   Solve the diffrential equation$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2+3y$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2+3y$$
$$dy=(2+3y)dx$$
$$\frac{dy}{2+3y}=dx$$

then I integrated bothsides..
$$\int\frac{dy}{2+3y}=\int{dx}$$

and this is what I think you should get but the book says otherwise...
$$\frac{1}{3}ln(2+3y)+c = x+c$$

I know I'm wrong about this but why is there no constant when we integrate the RHS? I'm assuming there's a 1 in front of the $dx$ and when you integrate you get $x+c$

If someone could explain why I'd be grateful.

Comment: You can put a constant $C_1$ on the left, and a constant $C_2$ on the right. But these can be combined into a single constant $C$ either on the left or the right. Note that it is not right to do as you did and use the *same* constant symbol on the left and right, for then you get cancellation.

Comment: use $c1 , c2 $ , combine them to make a single $c3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally speaking, this solution should be
$$\frac{1}{3}\ln(2+3y)+c_1=x+c_2.$$
But we can also write this
$$\frac{1}{3}\ln(2+3y)=x+c_2-c_1.$$
But we can define a new constant $c=c_2-c_1$, and write this
$$\frac{1}{3}\ln(2+3y)=x+c.$$
Usually, we skip all the middle steps and jump straight to the end.

Answer (score 3):

The two sides can take different constants, say $c_1$ and $c_2$. But then you can move both constants to one side and call $c = c_1 - c_2$, which also can take any value.

The lesson here is that $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be same or different, in contrary to what your form says.